Experience Editor 500 error
I'm getting the following error on certain pages (I have a Header component on this page) when I add this Header component.
ERROR [JSS] Error occurred during POST to remote rendering host: `https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.sitecorecloud.io:443/api/editing/render`

ERROR The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. Exception: System.Net.WebException Message: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. Source: System    at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)    at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)    at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.RenderEngine.Invoke[T](String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)

I tried this from official documentation and this this but it does not work.
All other pages are working fine.
EDIT, error screenshot


Anything specific in logs? Please also try to change it too predefined component like promo (Remove Header). If that's work than issue is with Header component.

Yes, I already tried to change to predefined component and it works, so, the issue is with Header component ONLY in Experience Editor, because on frontend side is working.

you need to look at the log files on your rendering host and see what the error is.

Yes, I looked and the error is the one I originally posted. I will update the answer with a screenshot.

Ensure that the URL is correct and verify any configuration settings related to the connection!

As Richard suggests in comments I looked at the log files, RenderingHost log specifically and the problem was missing fields.
